# what is CheckSum for in the PE header file?

Tags: windows, checksum

as I know that we need the /release switch for linker to create the checksum value, can anyone tell me what is this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last I heard, checksums were validated *on drivers only* when loaded by Windows - presumably as a first defence against viruses.

Comment: Not so much for viruses, more for disk corruption